Curie and „magnetism way to strong for known physics“ (at that time)
On this question What is the motivation behind the Heisenberg Hamiltonian naturallyInconsistent commented

The rockstar Curie couple had already worked out quite a lot of the theory around magnetism via mean field approximation, and deduced that the experimentally observed magnetism is way too strong to be explained by known physics at the time.

Can you please explain this in more detail and, if possible, provide sources.

I think a good question needs to be self-contained. This question is not self-contained.

I have added an answer about the magnetic field in the Weiss mean field approximation, which I think naturally Inconsistent is refering to. It's not quite clear to me though, whether my interpretation of the comment is right

If there is some quote of the Curies or Weiss saying that ferromagnetism is too strong I would like to see it. This could be discussed in History of Science and Mathematics SE.

While Pierre Curie did undertake an early experimental study of ferromagnetism, as far as I can tell it was actually Pierre Weiss who first introduced the concept of this large magnetic field.
Weiss developed a model of ferromagnetism based on paramagnetism. In paramagnetic materials, you see a magnetisation if you apply an external magnetic fields, because the magnetic moments of the atoms align in the external field. In ferromagnetic materials, you have a non-zero magnetisation without an external field. Weiss' model is based on the idea that this magnetisation is caused by an internal magnetic field, which he called molecular field.
The complete calculations to understand the model are contained in my reference, but to estimate the magnitude of this molecular field, we can use this approach: ferromagnetic order is caused by the magnetic moments aligning in the molecular field $H_{mol}$. At the Curie temperature $T_C$, ferromagnetic order breaks down. Therefore
$$k_B T_C = \mu_B H_{mol}.$$
From this, we get $H_{mol} = 1500 $ T for iron, a very strong field that can't be explained by anything we (then or now) know about iron.
We now know what there simply is no such magnetic field. The alignment of magnetic moments is caused by a local, electrostatic interaction between nearby atoms. From this perspective, the Weiss model is a mean field theory for this interaction, which explains why it captures some of the behaviour of ferromagnetism, even though the molecular field has no physical meaning.
References:
Main source: (2006). Weiss Molecular Field Model. In: Magnetism in the Solid State. Solid-State Sciences, vol 134. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-30981-0_6
Paper by Weiss (french): P. Weiss, J. de Physique 6 661 (1907). https://hal.science/jpa-00241247/en
